# apply (ocean) modifier in a gradient/

Tags: ocean-simulation

I would like to apply the ocean modifier in a non-uniform way. I basically want the edges of the are o the ocean to be flat and gradually increase in height towards the center of the tile. Could you give me some tips how to achieve this? Thanks!

Comment: Something like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4ORCo.gif)?

Comment: yes, pretty much..!

Answer (score 2):

you can use this node setup:

[image]

to get this:

[image]

Basically i just lay a grid "under" the ocean modifier and mix the grid vectors with the ocean vertex positions.

Of course you could use some cleverer math than i did to blend the value. I just used length (i prerequisite the your ocean modifier has the middle in 0,0,0 - but of course you could use a vector distance node from whatever point you want instead of length) to determine some mix factor for the both positions.

Note: i used a standard ocean modifier. If you change the spatial or resolution size, you have to adapt the sizexy/verticesxy accordingly.

[image]

Comment: thanks a lot mate for the alternative!

Comment: Nice one, Chris! Mixing a vector. That's crazy :D -- If you don't like the math calculations you also can plug in a vertex group or an image, and use it with GN. This should work, too.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a solution with modifiers.

The *Ocean* modifier has no vertex group to control the influence. But you can use another larger plane and deform it with either the *Shrinkwrap* **(1)** or the *Surface Deform* modifier **(2)**. Both support a vertex group for the falloff.

[image: screenshot 1]

To create the larger plane just create a single face the same size as the faces of the *Ocean* modifier. Then add & apply 2 *Array* modifiers (in X and Y directions) to expand the plane.

In the *Weight Paint* mode paint the weights for the influence of the modifier. The created vertex group (*Ocean Displ*) is then used for the modifier.

[image: weight paint]

The *Shrinkwrap* modifier must be set to *Project* mode with `[X)` *Negative* and `[X]` *Positive* axe directions enabled.

While for the *Surface Deform* modifier you need to specify the vertex group and press the *Bind* button.

Example:
[image: animation]

Comment: +1 nice solution!

Comment: amazing, cheers for taking the time!